# React Native - Axios - Trying to upload image

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, post, axios

I am new to React Native and trying to upload Image with Axios but getting: `Request failed with status code 500`

I don't have backend problem because I can upload image with postman and everything is fine.

Here is my code, please help me if you know a solution, when I console log data, all the data are fine!!

```js
const data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', name);
        data.append('childrenImage', childrenImage);
        data.append('parent', parent)

        console.log(data);

        axios.post('http://192.168.0.24:3000/childrens/', data, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': auth,
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`
                }
            }
        ).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            console.log(res.status);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
```

Comment: where did you put the uri file ?

Answer (score 13):

Can't be sure but in my case I had to add a 'name' field to the file. Following other advices, I've end up with something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';

function upload (data, images, token) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('data', data);
  images.forEach((image, i) => {
    formData.append('images', {
      ...image,
      uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? image.uri : image.uri.replace('file://', ''),
      name: `image-${i}`,
      type: 'image/jpeg', // it may be necessary in Android. 
    });
  });
  const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001',
  });
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
  client.post('/items/save', formData, headers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks MIME type is what i was missing.

Comment: Make sure to set both `name` and `type` as the properties of the object which is passed as the 2nd argument to `formData.append` (as is done in the answer, It is easy to overlook that), for me, not setting them, caused weird problems on server by which I mean server did not recognized the file upload operation.

Comment: Very helpful example, though I'm not clear, what keys/values is `...image` spreading into the object?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and this is what helped me.

1. In android/app/src/main/java/com/{yourProject}/MainApplication.java
   comment the below line :

   ```
   initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())
   ```
2. In android/app/src/debug/java/com/{yourProject}/ReactNativeFlipper.java
   comment in line 43 :

   ```
   builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
   ```
3. Code for image upload :

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('UserId', 'abc@abc.com');
      formData.append('VisitId', '28596');
      formData.append('EvidenceCapturedDate', '09/10/2019 13:28:20');
      formData.append('EvidenceCategory', 'Before');
      formData.append('EvidenceImage', {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${path}` : path,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
      axios({
        url: UrlString.BaseUrl + UrlString.imageUpload,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle success******');
          console.log(response.data);

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle failure******');
          console.log(response);
        });
   ```

Comment: I have the same issue..I can upload from post man but cant upload from real device both ios and android.. i tried this and not work for me

Comment: @ABM can help me out. file upload to server using form data with axios is not working

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.
First I needed to remove file:// from my uri so i added the code :

```
const fileURL = this.state.pickedImaged.uri;
const cleanURL = fileURL.replace("file://", "");
```

and than what caused the problem was the image type, please check what image type you try to upload and what you can upload depending on the backend you are using.

Hope will help someone who has the same problem

Comment: Can you please edit it to your full code? I don't know where to put the uri. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
Accept: "application/json"

Answer (score 1):

Two things are important on Android; Setting the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

Also, make sure the type on your Blob is a valid MimeType. In my case, I was passing `type: 'image'`, in iOS, it worked fine, but on android, it didn't work until I updated it to `type: 'image/jpeg'` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

FLIPPER_VERSION=0.33.1 to FLIPPER_VERSION=0.41.0

Need to update your Flipper_Version above or equal = 0.41.0 
after update it's working fine.

Answer (score -2):

in react I use the following code:

```
//Set file in state
fileChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] })
  }

//Set form data and request in axios
uploadHandler = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log(this.state.selectedFile)
    formData.append('file', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/uploadFile', formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        }
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

In the back-end receive the file and test with console.log(req.files)

I hope to have helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is what I am doing also, it just doesn't work with react native !!

Comment: i saw some post they remove file:///