# react-native upload image and data to api using axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

how to upload image to api using axios

i want to upload image with data to api using axios
i try with formdata but it did not work see below my code

[image: how it work in postman]

and this is my code

```js
uploadToServer= () => {
    const file =this.state.photo



let formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('sale_id', 1)
formdata.append('note_type_id', 4)

formdata.append('description', "test")

formdata.append('note_content_item', "test")

formdata.append('Note', file)


   axios.post('api',
        {data:formdata},{headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization':'xx'
            }

          })
        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
        .catch(error => console.error(error)); 

}
```

i try a lot of solution but it give me 
Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: Spelling error on 'Content-type' inside axios request. Change that and try again?

Comment: thank you @MickVader
now i got error code 500??

Comment: Do you own the server or have access to it? If so the server side stack trace of when your request pings could help narrow it down. I would guess it has something got to do with your formdata object though if postman is successful.. [EDIT] try adding formdata straight into the params of the axios.post request: `axios.post('api', formdata, {headers:...);`

Comment: axios.post('api', formdata, {headers:...);

now i  have access but i got this response 

{
    "response": {
        "message": "Can not save file",
        "response_code": 10
    }
}

in the postman i got this response if i change the KEY data to something else

Comment: so i change the key from formdata to data 

let data = new FormData()
data.append('sale_id', '1')
data.append('note_type_id', '4')

data.append('description', "test")

data.append('note_content_item', "test")






   axios.post('api',data
       ,{headers: {

but still got the same thing can not save file

Comment: Please try this out. It helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161651/8013132

Answer (score 2):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the server.
You can request like this (using fetch):

```
let formdata = new FormData()

formdata.append('description', "test")

let i = {
    uri: image.path,
    type: 'multipart/form-data',
    name: `image.jpg`,
};
formdata.append('image', i);

fetch(YourApi,{
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
        body: formdata
}).then(response => {
    response.text().then((res)=>{
        console.warn(res)
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.warn('error')
})
```