# How to upload file to server in react native expo

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to upload file to the server from my react native app. I get the file from using `ImagePicker` but unable to upload it on server. I every time server gives me 400.
Any help would be great.

Here is my code

> MyProfile.tsx

```
const handleProfileUpdate = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera Permissions");
      } else {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 1,
          //base64: true,
        });

        const localUri = result.uri;
        console.log("ImagePIcker", localUri);
        if (!result.cancelled) {
          setProfileImage(localUri);
          updateProfile(localUri);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

> userActions.ts

```
export const updateUserProfilePicture = (url: string) => async (
  dispatch: any
) => {

  var data = new FormData();  
  data.append("profilepic", url);
  console.log("profileUrl", url);
  const _rest = new restServices();
  const token = await _rest.getAccessToken();
  
  var config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: "put",
    url: "http://xxxxxxxxxx/user/profilePic",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    },
    data: data,
  };
  axios(config)
    
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("profileUpdate", res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("profileupdate", err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use contetType:multipart/form-data

 this might help you,

[React Native - Axios - Trying to upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936988/react-native-axios-trying-to-upload-image)

[How do I set multipart in axios with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react)