# How can i upload image to server using axios in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I want to upload an image file to the server in react native, how can i do so? 
Here is my code :

In my `index.js` Which is my entry point I have set axios default configurations :

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = BaseUrl;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
```

Now in my `profileEdit.js`, where I need to upload a profile image

```
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('profile_picture',
      {uri: imageResponse.uri, name: imageResponse.fileName, type: 'image/jpg'});

// imageResponse is a response object that I m getting from React native  ImagePicker 

    axios.post('profile/picture/', data,
       {
          headers: {
                    "Authorization": "JWT " + this.state.token,
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                  }
        }).then(response => {
                console.log('Profile picture uploaded successfully', response);

        }).catch(error => {
              console.log('Failed to upload profile image', error);
              console.log('Error response',error.response);

        });
```

But this giving me network error, while other APIs are working fine.

I followed the solution given here [How to upload image to server using axios in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830312/how-to-upload-image-to-server-using-axios-in-react-native)

[image: This is the error response I am getting]

This is the error response I am getting.

And my request header is like this
[image]

I don't want to use any other package such as [react native fetch blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

More links that I followed :

- [axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Can anyone please tell me where I m doing wrong or how shall I approach to this problem. ty

Comment: Just try to change 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'.... it will work, I took reference from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Answer (score 3):

I think your header for the Axios POST request may be incorrect since you're using a `FormData()` constructor to store your image data:

You may want to try the following instead:

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('profile_picture',{
  uri: imageResponse.uri,
  name: imageResponse.fileName,
  type: 'image/jpg'}
);

axios.post('profile/picture/', data,
  {
    headers: {
      'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
      ...data.getHeaders()
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me simply work

```
const oFormData = new FormData();
oFormData.append("image", {
uri: images.uri,
type: images.type,
name: images.fileName
});

axios.post(servicesUrl.imageupload, oFormData);
```